# Is there any leaflet plugin to show historical data?

Tags: plugins, leaflet

I want to show some historical data via leaflet map, for example, show some universities on map based on their establishing year by sequence, i guess if i write it by myself i would use some setInterval or else function, but i prefer some existing plugin if it's available, any one can give some hint? thanks.

Thanks & Regards,
Martin.

Comment: Do you mean you have the data [university, year], and you want to display it with some animation?

Comment: yes, ghybs, i want to show some animation, for example, there're 100 universities which were established at diff years, there're are two mode to show the animation, the most preferred mode is i put a time slider which i can adjust start year, end year, and drag the slider for a sliding window, to see the corresponding universities among these windows. the second preferred mode is to auto broadcast them year by year which would be done thru setInterval or some 3rd code. for the manual mode, maybe i can use D3 or echart slider, but still need some adapting with leaflet, any comment you can give?